# Mac OS X install on PC Hard Drive?

Tags: mac-osx

I have a brand new desktop system that i'd like to put os x on. its a brand new system inside and out. i built it from scratch. its an intel p4 3.2 ghz. I also have a MacBook which is about a year old and I love os x. I have the os x disc that came with my macbook and I have re-installed on a new hard drive on my laptop. Is it possible to use the install disc to install os x on my new system? there has never been an OS on the new hard drive. The disc says For Mac Computers, Mac OS X Install Disc 1 (I have the 2nd disc also), Mac OS Version 10.5.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Is it possible to use the install disc to install os x on my new system?" No, the OEM mac install disks are specific to each mac model and cannot be used on other mac models let alone another pc.

http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

http://www.osx86project.org/ These sites will help you get started on an os x install on a standard pc.

OS X on a standard pc though is a violation of the license agreement of os x.  It is not supported in any fashion through apple.

I have tried this before and it can be done, however make sure to check out that wiki page and see what hardware people have been successful with.  There are a limited number of drivers available for os x.  It is not like windows when it comes to hardware support. I got it to work, but it did not work well on the hardware I had.  Many people have had great success though.  It is a great learning experience none the less.

Answer (score 3):

While possible, it does violate the licensing for OSX... meaning it is for Mac hardware only (see Psystar case for examples).  If you were to want to take the law and your freedom into your own hands and do this, there are a lot of resources on the web that you can look up.  A quick search for the right search phrase got me several hits.  Good Luck.

Comment: Yes, the Psystar saga is a good example.

Comment: A quick search for the right search phrase got me several hits, but no  succesfuly results.